# Could not load find main class after maven jar build

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build `jar` using maven, problem that despite success build.
When I run jar, I get error: `Could not find load main class...`

Here is my file structure:[image]
`ATEParser.java` is my main class.

Here is my build from `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>parser.main.ATEParser</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I build with: `mvn install`.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class AutocadToExcelParser.jar
```

when I run `java AutocadToExcelParser.jar`.

Maybe someone can point what I missed, or what could be the reasons of error.

Comment: What exactly is the error and what exact command did you run?

Comment: try adding ```-jar``` assuming the path to the jar is correct.

Comment: Voting to close as typo: you need to have `java -jar AutocadToExcelParser.jar`.

Comment: get `no main manifest attribute, in..`

Comment: You should run that on the jar-with-dependencies.

Comment: Thank you that helped :)

Comment: Bonus question: can I expect that it will execute on double click also?

Comment: It should. It depends how JAR extensions are linked in Windows but, by default, I think it should.